# Manipulating JSON into observable array collections

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, knockout.js

I'm seeking advice how to process this JSON:

```
[{
  "title":"Things",
  "text":"1. Raindrops on roses 2. Whiskers on kittens 3. Bright copper kettles 4. Warm woolen mittens 5. Brown paper packages"
},{
  "title":"Colors",
  "text":"1. White 2. Blue 3. Red 4. Yellow 5. Green"
},{
  "title":"Animals",
  "text":"1. Dog 2. Rabbit 3. Cat 4. Squirrel 5. Duck"
},{
  "title":"Colors",
  "text":"1. Red 2. Blue 3. Orange 4. Green 5. Purple"
},{
  "title":"Animals",
  "text":"1. Bear 2. Bird 3. Duck 4. Squirrel 5. Rabbit"
},{
  "title":"Colors",
  "text":"1. Yellow 2. White 3. Black 4. Brown 5. Blue"
}]
```

to return these collections of observable arrays:

- Title: Colors, Count: 3, Items:

  - Name: White, Score: 9, Count: 2
  - Name: Blue, Score: 9, Count: 3
  - Name: Red, Score: 8, Count: 2
  - Name: Yellow, Score: 7, Count: 2
  - Name: Black, Score: 3, Count: 1
  - Name: Orange, Score: 3, Count: 1
  - Name: Green, Score: 3, Count: 2
  - Name: Brown, Score: 2, Count: 1
  - Name: Purple, Score: 1, Count: 1

---

- Title: Animals, Count: 2, Items:

  - Name: Bear, Score: 5, Count: 1
  - Name: Dog, Score: 5, Count: 1
  - Name: Rabbit, Score: 5, Count: 2
  - Name: Bird, Score: 4, Count: 1
  - Name: Duck, Score: 4, Count: 2
  - Name: Squirrel, Score: 4, Count: 2
  - Name: Cat, Score: 3, Count: 1

---

- Title: Things, Count: 1, Items:

  - Name: Raindrops on roses, Score: 5, Count: 1
  - Name: Whiskers on kittens, Score: 4, Count: 1
  - Name: Bright copper kettles, Score: 3, Count: 1
  - Name: Warm woolen mittens, Score: 2, Count: 1
  - Name: Brown paper packages, Score: 1, Count: 1

---

To explain, I need to do the following:

1. Group all arrays by `title`, count their frequency and return new List objects e.g. `Title: Colors, Count: 3`
2. Split each `text` item by number separator to create an array of items, count their frequency, assign them a score based on index position (i.e. [0] = 5 to [4] = 1), sum their scores and return new Item objects e.g. `Name: White, Score: 9, Count: 2`
3. Sort the `Lists` collection by `Count` and the `Items` collections by `Score`, `Count` and `Name`.

I've created the following javascript objects:

```
function List(title, items, count) {
    var self = this;
        self.Title = title;
        self.Count = count;
        self.Items = ko.observableArray(items);
}

function Item(name, count, score) {
    var self = this;
        self.Name = name;
        self.Count = count;
        self.Score = score;
}
```

I've looked into various approaches I had intended to attack this task with underscore.js but I was put off by reported poor performance at iterating arrays.

I anticipate the `JSON` file to get much larger than the sample I've shown so performance will be important.

Hopefully, some can suggest the best approach to achieve my objectives and perhaps demonstrate a good starting point.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using [Lo-Dash 2.2.1](http://lodash.com/) in this example, but you could easily swap in [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) as their libraries `_.each` signatures are basically identical.

<kbd>**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DVJ66/5/)**</kbd>

```
var collection = [{
  "title":"Things",
  "text":"1. Raindrops on roses 2. Whiskers on kittens 3. Bright copper kettles 4. Warm woolen mittens 5. Brown paper packages"
},{
  "title":"Colors",
  "text":"1. White 2. Blue 3. Red 4. Yellow 5. Green"
},{
  "title":"Animals",
  "text":"1. Dog 2. Rabbit 3. Cat 4. Squirrel 5. Duck"
},{
  "title":"Colors",
  "text":"1. Red 2. Blue 3. Orange 4. Green 5. Purple"
},{
  "title":"Animals",
  "text":"1. Bear 2. Bird 3. Duck 4. Squirrel 5. Rabbit"
},{
  "title":"Colors",
  "text":"1. Yellow 2. White 3. Black 4. Brown 5. Blue"
}];

//Store all the collections in a single place.
var collections = {}; 
_.each(collection, function(item){

    //Does the collection exist?
    if(!collections[item.title]){
        //No? Add a new one
        collections[item.title] = {Title:'', Items: {} };    
    }

    //Split out the parts of the text by number period
    var parts = item.text.split(/[0-9]+\./); 
    if(parts.length > 0){
        parts.shift(); //remove the first entry in the array since it will be blank   
    }

    //Iterate over each part text we found
    _.each(parts, function(partName, i){

        partName = partName.trim(); //remove whitespace

        //Try to get an existing reference to the part
        var part = collections[item.title].Items[partName]; 

        //If the part doesn't exist
        if(!part){

            //Create a new one and add it to the collection
            part = { Score: 0, Count: 0 }; 
            collections[item.title].Items[partName] = part; 
        }

        //Increment the score by the ordinal position
        part.Score += i; 

        //Increment the count by 1
        part.Count++; 
    }); 
});


//Store the final array of collections here
var finalData = []; 

//Iterate over our current collection object
_.each(collections, function(collection, i){

    var data = []; 

    //Convert the Items "hashtables"/objects into arrays
    for(var key in collection.Items){

        data.push({
            'Name': key,    
            'Score': collection.Items[key].Score, 
            'Count': collection.Items[key].Count
        }); 

    }

    collection.Items = data; //replace the Items object with the array
    collection.Count = data.length; //compute the current count. (Although you could always call Items.length)
    finalData.push(collection); //add the collection to the array.
});

console.log(finalData);
```

**Results**

```
[
  {
    "Title": "Things",
    "Items": [
      {
        "Name": "Raindrops on roses",
        "Score": 0,
        "Count": 1
      },
      {
        "Name": "Whiskers on kittens",
        "Score": 1,
        "Count": 1
      },
      {
        "Name": "Bright copper kettles",
        "Score": 2,
        "Count": 1
      },
      {
        "Name": "Warm woolen mittens",
        "Score": 3,
        "Count": 1
      },
      {
        "Name": "Brown paper packages",
        "Score": 4,
        "Count": 1
      }
    ],
    "Count": 5
  },
  {
    "Title": "Colors",
    "Items": [
      {
        "Name": "White",
        "Score": 1,
        "Count": 2
      },
      {
        "Name": "Blue",
        "Score": 6,
        "Count": 3
      },
      {
        "Name": "Red",
        "Score": 2,
        "Count": 2
      },
      {
        "Name": "Yellow",
        "Score": 3,
        "Count": 2
      },
      {
        "Name": "Green",
        "Score": 7,
        "Count": 2
      },
      {
        "Name": "Orange",
        "Score": 2,
        "Count": 1
      },
      {
        "Name": "Purple",
        "Score": 4,
        "Count": 1
      },
      {
        "Name": "Black",
        "Score": 2,
        "Count": 1
      },
      {
        "Name": "Brown",
        "Score": 3,
        "Count": 1
      }
    ],
    "Count": 9
  },
  {
    "Title": "Animals",
    "Items": [
      {
        "Name": "Dog",
        "Score": 0,
        "Count": 1
      },
      {
        "Name": "Rabbit",
        "Score": 5,
        "Count": 2
      },
      {
        "Name": "Cat",
        "Score": 2,
        "Count": 1
      },
      {
        "Name": "Squirrel",
        "Score": 6,
        "Count": 2
      },
      {
        "Name": "Duck",
        "Score": 6,
        "Count": 2
      },
      {
        "Name": "Bear",
        "Score": 0,
        "Count": 1
      },
      {
        "Name": "Bird",
        "Score": 1,
        "Count": 1
      }
    ],
    "Count": 7
  }
]
```

Comment: Wow - great answer. Thanks very much. I'm just working through it and will reply again later.

Comment: Did you get a chance to work through it? I didn't add the `ko. observableArray` components as I figured you were more interested in the transformation routine, but they should be super easy to add in. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Hi Brandon, sorry for the late reply. I did actually try to recreate your solution as pure knockout (models, ko.observableArrays and ko.utils) because there is more functionality I need to incorporate that I suspect knockouts MVVM would lend itself nicely to. e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22003718/amending-link-text-and-array-value-text-based-on-dropdown-selection I was hoping for a clear answer to this question before I replied to yours. Like I said, performance is paramount so if lo-dash's _each is faster than knockout's ArrayForEach (for example), I'd go with that.